# jquery imagesloaded display nodes as soon as they are ready

Tags: jquery, children

looked at existing answers, but can't get my head around this.

i am using jquery + imagesloaded + masonry to display nodes on a page.

The page structure is like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"><img /></div>
  <div class="child"><img /></div>
  <div class="child"><img /></div>
</div>
```

currently, the code does this:
1- gets parent content
2- waits until images of all children are loaded
3- prints them.

What i am trying is
1- get parent, get each child
2- as soon as images loaded for first child, print it

here is my current code.

```
var $container = jQuery('#parent');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.masonry({   //this part prints children
  itemSelector: '.child',
  columnWidth: 410,
  gutterWidth: 30,
  isFitWidth: true,
  isResizable:true
});
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: The .masonry method has no printing functionality; but you can find a plugin with which you can print individual masonry elements or the entire container here http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/#.UCT9uRx9C_g

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `imagesLoaded()` should be called on the children, because they contain the images

I checked the function out and the right selector should be:

```
$('#parent .child img')
```

And another addition, I think I misunderstood your question... you want it to fire after only the images of the first child are loaded?

Then do this:

```
$('#parent .child').eq(0).imagesLoaded({});
```

Comment: How could that be done. I am newbie to jquery. I am using the demo code given in jquery infinitescroll plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the many edits, hat to check the function imagesLoaded() out, first :-) I think the given selector now, should be right!

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, so just another solution occurred ;-)